# EmberJS: `ember serve --environment=test` renders blank page

Tags: ember.js, integration-testing, test-environments

My team is moving to use Cypress for integration testing rather than Embers Acceptance tests. Before, we would just run `ember test` which set the environment to "test". Now, I don't want to run embers testing suite but I still want the "test" version of our app. So I want to be able to run `ember serve --environment=test`. However, I noticed that when I did this, I just get a blank screen. The weirdest thing is that when I change it to `ember serve --environment=haha` (haha being a random environment name that never existed before), I start seeing the app hit my routes like I would expect. I start actually getting application errors in code we wrote in the source, whereas with the test environment, I couldn't even hit a `console.log` in the `application` route.

I want to be able to serve my app with the test environment because we're using it for testing. Is this possible? I'm specifically wondering if there's a bunch of magic under the hood with that environment that makes this impossible or if it's just something else I need to do that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what side effects this would have, but you can get your app running with `ember serve --environment=test` if you comment out two lines in your `config/environment.js` file:

```js
if (environment === 'test') {
  // ENV.APP.rootElement = '#ember-testing'
  // ENV.APP.autoboot = false
}
```